# 406(Not Acceptable) error when downloading pdf files with Azure app services

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

### **WebAPI**: .NetCore 2.0; **Front/APP**: Angular 4;

I have a method in my webapi that exports to pdf file, this working on my machine but after publish on Azure isnt working. This is the method on controller:

```
 [HttpGet("DownloadPDF")]
    public IActionResult DownloadPropostaPDF(int propostaId)
    {
        var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        try
        {
            var nomeProposta = _propostasAppService.CriarProposta(propostaId, "Juntos");
            var proposta = _propostasAppService.BuscarPorId(propostaId);
            if (nomeProposta != null)
            {
                string contentType = "application/pdf";
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;
                var pdfPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Arquivos", proposta.Numero, nomeProposta.Replace(".docx", ".pdf"));
                var docxPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Arquivos", proposta.Numero, nomeProposta);
                if (_propostasAppService.GerarPdf(docxPath))
                {
                    var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(docxPath);
                    var result = new FileContentResult(file, contentType)
                    {
                        FileDownloadName = nomeProposta.Replace(".docx", ".pdf")
                    };
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.StatusCode = 404;
                    return null;
                }
            }
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            telemetry.TrackException(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

App component code:

```
downloadPropostaPDF(idProposta) {
this.propostasService.getProposta(idProposta).subscribe(proposta => {
  var nomeArquivo = proposta.formatoPropostaNome + " Blend IT " + proposta.numero
    + " - " + proposta.titulo + " - " + proposta.clienteNomeFantasia
    + " - v" + proposta.versao + ".pdf"
  this.propostasService.downloadPdf(idProposta, "Juntos").subscribe(data => {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
    saveAs(blob, nomeArquivo);
  },
    error => {
      console.log(error)
    }
  )
})
```

}

App Service:

```
downloadPdf(propostaId: number, formatoDocumento: any): any {
    const _url = Configuration.apiUrl + 'api/propostas/DownloadPdf/' + '?propostaId=' + propostaId
    return this.http.get(_url, { headers: this.headersBlobPdf, responseType: 'blob' })
}

Headers:
    Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
    Origin:http://propostas-homolog.azurewebsites.net
    X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:(50FE08B74C0BC8F9BE1441A68EB6B34)
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
    Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.9
```

How I fix this? Working only localhost.

Tks

Comment: When you say "isn't working", what is it doing instead? Is there an error message other than just the response code?

Comment: Just http error response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is some underlying exception happening which is causing the error code to be returned from the application. Try taking a CLR profiler trace by going to the Azure portal and then choosing "diagnose and solve problems " and under that go to "Diagnostic as a service" .Over there, make sure that the CLR profiler diagnoser is selected and hit the run button. Once the profiler  trace is started, try to reproduce your issue by making a few requests to your Web API. The profiler will stop after 60 seconds automatically and will generate a report. The report has a failed requests section which will show you all the requests which failed and associated exceptions, if it find one....hope this helps in narrowing down the issue.